# How to filter using timedelta when a field can be None?

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to create a method in a `PlayerAt` table to select records from a `PlayerOc` table based upon a filter that uses `timedelta`. Here's the cut down class:

```
class PlayerAt(Base):

    id_ = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    birth_date = sa.Column(sa.Date, index=True)

    def return_player_oc_records(self):
        session = sa.orm.object_session(self)
        qry = session.query(PlayerOc)
        qry = qry.outerjoin(PlayerAt)
        qry = qry.filter(PlayerOc.birth_date >= self.birth_date - dt.timedelta(weeks=4))
        recs = qry.all()
        return recs
```

However, when I execute the method I get the error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'NoneType' and 'datetime.timedelta'
```

This is because some of the `PlayerAt` records don't have a `birth_date`.

I've tried converting the filter into:

```
qry = qry.filter(PlayerOc.birth_date >= sa.func.IF(self.birth_date != None, self.birth_date - dt.timedelta(weeks=4), None))
```

However, I get the same error.

Any ideas on a fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out a way to use `DATEDIFF` to solve this:

```
qry = qry.filter(sa.func.datediff(PlayerOc.birth_date, self.birth_date) >= -28)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use and

```
qry = qry.filter((self.birth_date.isnot(None)) & (PlayerOc.birth_date >=  self.birth_date - dt.timedelta(weeks=4)))
```

If you want to keep no birthday, you can use or condition

```
qry = qry.filter((self.birth_date.is_(None)) | (PlayerOc.birth_date >=  self.birth_date - dt.timedelta(weeks=4)))
```

Comment: Hey. Thanks for giving this a shot. Sadly I get the same error with the first option :(

Comment: updated to new method

Comment: Getting the same error for records that don't have a `birth_date` but also now getting a new error for those that do have a `birth_date` - `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'bool' and 'BinaryExpression'`

Comment: Just updated. Try the `.isnot(None)` expression rather than `!= None`. Maybe it's a version issue.

Comment: Tried `isnot` before :( This gives the error `AttributeError: 'datetime.date' object has no attribute 'isnot'`. I think this issue is something to do with me trying to query using a method that accesses fields from `self` rather than having a separate query that uses the classes directly

Comment: Ah yes. I believe so.  I don't think the filtering belong to the model class. In the model-view-controller paradigm, the processing should be in the controller module.